# AngularJS keypress event listener - NOT INPUT ELEMENT

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to create a DIV that responds to keypress events, specifically the up arrow and down arrow. When the div is open, I want the window/document to respond to specific keypress events. I've seen JQuery solutions, but I'd rather not use JQuery. What's the best way to accomplish this?

Specifically, I will have different audio volume images and I want these images to change with each keypress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I found was by using vanilla JavaScript:

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
    // some code here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    $scope.keypress = function($event) {
     $scope.Key = $event.keyCode
     };
```

You can write in the div with ng-keydown="keypress($event)"
codepen URL for reference-http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/beEQRE

  -

---

Comment: added alert for up and down arrow

Comment: No that's not what I'm looking for. I don't want an input field involved. When a div is open, I want the window to respond to specific keypress events.